# How to simulate timeout in response to a Rest request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, timeout

I have a Rest API implemented with Spring Boot 2. To check some client behavior on timeout, how can I simulate that condition in my testing environment? The server should regularly receive the request and process it (in fact, in production timeouts happen due to random network slowdowns and large big response payloads).

Would adding a long sleep be the proper simulation technique? Is there any better method to really have the server "drop" the response?

Answer (score 1):

Needing sleeps to test your code is considered bad practice. Instead you want to replicate the exception you receive from the timeout, e.g. `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` when using `RestTemplate.exchange`.

Then you can write a test as such:

```
public class FooTest

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        when(restTemplate.exchange(...)).thenThrow(new java.net.SocketTimeoutException())
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        // TODO
    }

}
```

That way you wont be twiddling your thumbs waiting for something to happen.

Comment: Does this test the server (Rest API)? I need to inspect the real client behavior (so no actual test frameworks are in place).

Comment: This is just an example. If you say the client timed out, as far as you are concerned this means an exception was thrown, after x amount of time. Wherever your code has this exception happen mock that method in your test to throw the exception immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep is one way to do it, but if you're writing dozens of tests like that then having to wait for a sleep will create a really long-running test suite.

The alternative would be to change the 'threshold' for timeout on the client side for testing. If in production your client is supposed to wait 5 seconds for a response, then in test change it to 0.5 seconds (assuming your server takes longer than that to respond) but keeping the same error handling logic.

The latter might not work in all scenarios, but it will definitely save you from having a test suite that takes 10+ mins to run.

Comment: Good point, that's why I'd rather prefer something like a connection drop than a sleep; I don't like having to change the client, but that could be a useful last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing which I did in my case .
Actually in my case, when my application is running in a production environment, we keep on polling trades from the API and sometimes it drops the connection by throwing an Exception *SSLProtocolException*.

What we did

```
int retryCount =5; 
while (true ){ 
    count++;
    try{ 
        //send an api request here
    }catch (Exception e){
         if(retryCount == count ) {
            throw e
            // here we can do a thread sleep. and try after that period to reconnect 
         }
    }
}
```

Similarly in your case some Exception it will throw catch that Exception and put your thread in Sleep for a while and after that again try for Connection the retryCount you can modify as per your requirment, in my case it was 5.

Comment: if you are using spring and netty webclient, use the buildin functionality instead of creating your own https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-retry